# Can 8-months old baby understand gravity in their water bottle?

Tags: bottle-feeding, water, drinking

My son likes to get bottle of water next to him and then he tries to drink it.

Sometimes he turns to his back and then he can drink it. But sometimes he just tries to suck it laying on his tummy, so the watter is on the bottom and because of gravity it is not possible to drink.

Is there a chance he would learn how the bottle works? (I know, that he won't understand the physics of it of course)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely!  This is how babies learn at this age - by testing things out and seeing what happens.  They don't understand why - but they also don't understand why their feet stick to the ground when they stand up, and that doesn't keep them from walking :)

Do be careful that he's not sucking too much air - that can lead to gas, which might be uncomfortable! If he does get too much air, you can burp him to relieve the pressure as long as it's still in the stomach.

You might also consider various forms of cup at this age - I think by 8 months we had introduced actual cups (metal cups, if you have a 30ml/1oz espresso cup this is just the right size!) occasionally, and sippy cups are also pretty commonly introduced around this age.  Just more options for him to try out and see how they work!

Comment: Don't forget to introduce him to the concept of "straw" at this point, too. It's very logical to go from "suck on nipple, get liquid" to "suck on straw, get liquid" when the kid's used to nursing. If you wait until he's fully used to "tip cup, get liquid" before you introduce the straw, you get a lot of "tip cup, get wet, change clothes". I've seen kids struggle to understand a straw because the parents waited too long.

Comment: I'm not a fan of straws for several reasons, but certainly if you're going to use straws that's a great point!

Comment: I've seen 2 and 3 year olds not understand that tipping the cup isn't necessary when using a straw, so unless your "not a fan of" extends to that age (and it's fine if that's the case, I'm sure you have your reasons), then it does help to teach 'em young.

Comment: @FreeMan I'm not a fan of straws at any age, adult included. :)  But absolutely agree with teaching it at this age if you're not of the same mind as me!

Comment: I don't use a sissy stick either, but for those who do... ;)

Comment: @Joe they also make cups with built-in straws, if the disposable nature is what you consider an issue. They’re honestly pretty neat.

Comment: There are as well a lot of different types of silicon straws that can just be washed, bend and chewed on.